# Excluding outliers, from the regression line fitted through a scatterplot, without removing the outlier from the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as follows, for which I run `ggplot` code below:

```
data <- structure(list(country_mean_rep = structure(c(73.6995708154506, 
93.5501285347044, 85.1529051987768, 91.1017369727047, 79.5562130177515, 
84.6751054852321, 89.8, 86.8826405867971, 94.2247191011236, 70.2321428571429, 
88.4107142857143), label = "label", format.stata = "%9.2f"), 
    country_mean_crime = c(0.0944206008583691, 0.0565552699228792, 
    0.0336391437308868, 0.205955334987593, 0.130177514792899, 
    0.282700421940928, 0.220512820512821, 0.415647921760391, 
    0.387640449438202, 0.200892857142857, 0.292207792207792), 
    country_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 
    14L, 16L, 20L), .Label = c("Albania", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", 
    "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", 
    "Cambodia", "Chile", "CostaRica", "Croatia", "Czech", "Ecuador", 
    "Estonia", "FYROM", "Georgia", "Germany", "Greece", "Guyana", 
    "Hungary", "Ireland", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kyrgyzstan", 
    "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Malawi", "Mali", "Moldova", "Philippines", 
    "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Senegal", "Serbia&Montenegro", 
    "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", 
    "SriLanka", "Tajikistan", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "Uzbekistan", 
    "Vietnam"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

# On which I like to run the following code:

ggplot(data, aes(x=country_mean_rep, y=country_mean_crime)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="linear", fill="linear"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x, ) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="quadratic", fill="quadratic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="cubic", fill="cubic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)) + 
  labs(colour="Functional Form", fill="Functional Form") +
  geom_text(aes(label=country_name), nudge_y=0.02) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now let's say that the Czech Republic is an outlier, which I want to remove for the fits I am doing (especially the linear one). Please note that I understand there is nothing wrong with the Czech Republic in the example, I need to know this for a proper outlier in my actual data.

Is there some way of excluding it only from the fit, while keeping the dot in the plot?

Comment: There are already two good answers, so I wont add another. Very similar to the answers below, you can subset the data in the call to your regression. `geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(country_name != "Czech"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to include different data plots:

```
ggplot(subset(data, country_name != 'Czech'), aes(x=country_mean_rep, y=country_mean_crime)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="linear", fill="linear"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x, ) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="quadratic", fill="quadratic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="cubic", fill="cubic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)) + 
  labs(colour="Functional Form", fill="Functional Form") +
  geom_point(data = data, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = country_mean_rep, y = country_mean_crime)) +
  geom_text(data = data, aes(label=country_name, x = country_mean_rep, y = country_mean_crime), inherit.aes = FALSE, nudge_y=0.02) +
  theme_bw()
```

In this case, the 3 linear models use the subsetted data whereas the calls to `geom_point` and `geom_text` do not inherit the original aestetics.

Comment: Great! Is there anyway to exclude a second country? I tried a couple of things without success.

Comment: You can use `!country_name %in% c('Czech', 'Azerbaijan')` in the subset call. Or, as @AndS. suggested, you can use `filter(data, country_name != 'Czech', country_name != ...)`

Comment: Or combine the two. I would do `. %>% filter(! country_name %in% c('Czech', 'Azerbaijan')`

Comment: I thought this would be a good FR for `dplyr`. It looks like it is already largely supported [Github Issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4508). In this case, instead of subsetting immediately, your `geom_smooth` calls would include `data = ~filter(.x, country_name != 'Czech')` @RuiBarrradas just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.
Start the plot with the subset of the data that excludes `"Czech"`. And only use the entire data set for the `data` argument of `geom_point`. Like this the point `"Czech"` will be plotted but excluded from the fits.

In fact, excluded from everything else. So if you want the `"Czech"` label you will have to also use `data = data` (the full data set) in `geom_text`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = subset(data, country_name != "Czech"), aes(x=country_mean_rep, y=country_mean_crime)) + 
  geom_point(data = data)
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="linear", fill="linear"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x, ) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="quadratic", fill="quadratic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="cubic", fill="cubic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)) + 
  labs(colour="Functional Form", fill="Functional Form") +
  geom_text(aes(label=country_name), nudge_y=0.02) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @Cole No, don't delete, you have beat me by 1 minute. I believe your answer should be the accepted one and mine an example of another way to specify the data to the several layers.